# Edit CoreData object then save context

Tags: ios, core-data, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary, nsset

I have two entities, one called `InProject` that has several attributes and one relationship. the relationship is with another entity called `Ins`.

I am editing one of the `Ins` that is related to `InProject`. I used `InProject` attribute `ID` which then returns a NSDictionary value that has several key-values one of which is for an array of `Ins`. I then find the Ins I need to edit in a for loop I edit them, but then I become unstuck because I am not sure how to save the contect of InProject with the *updated `Ins`

I need to figure out how to save `InProject` after I have overwritten the `Ins` attributes I need to update.

This is what my code looks like after battling this problem:

```
- (void)editSelectedins:(NSString *)projIDString UpdatedNSD:(NSMutableDictionary *)updatedNSD DPC:(int)dpc{

        // get context
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

        if (context == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Nil");
        }
        else {
            NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
            NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"InsProject" inManagedObjectContext:context];
            [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

            NSError *error;
            NSMutableArray *InsProjectDictionaryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

            for (InsProject *insProj in fetchedObjects) {
                NSMutableDictionary *tempInsProjectDictionaryArray = [[ NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

                [tempInsProjectDictionaryArray setObject:insProj.companyName forKey:@"CompanyName"];
                [tempInsProjectDictionaryArray setObject:insProj.projNo forKey:@"ProjNo"];
                [tempInsProjectDictionaryArray setObject:insProj.desc forKey:@"Desc"];
                [tempInsProjectDictionaryArray setObject:insProj.guid forKey:@"GUID"];
                [tempInsProjectDictionaryArray setObject:insProj.projID forKey:@"ProjID"];
                [tempInsProjectDictionaryArray setObject:insProj.ins forKey:@"ins"];

                [InsProjectDictionaryArray addObject:tempInsProjectDictionaryArray];
            }

            // now that you have the InsProjects, choose the one you are curently working on in insView using the projectID
            NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ProjID==%@",projIDString];
            [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

            // new array with one value that was created using the NSPredicate ProjID
            NSArray *tempInsProjectArray = [InsProjectDictionaryArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

            // get ins array out of the NSDictionary to edit
            NSSet *inssForInsProject = tempInsProjectArray[0][@"ins"];
            NSMutableArray *tempAllinss = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // this will contain everything, that means all repeated values are included

            for (Items* currItem in [inssForInsProject allObjects]) {
                NSArray *keys = [[[currItem entity] attributesByName] allKeys];
                NSDictionary *dict = [currItem dictionaryWithValuesForKeys:keys];
                [tempAllinss addObject:dict];
            }

            NSArray *myArray = [tempAllinss copy];

            // get the correct items from myArray anything whos dpc matches the dpc parameter of this method
            NSMutableArray *editedinsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            for (int i = 0; i < [myArray count]; i++) {
                NSMutableDictionary *tempinssDictionary = [myArray objectAtIndex:i];

                // if you get a match put it into the new editedinsArray to be edited
                if ([[tempinssDictionary objectForKey:@"dpc"] integerValue] == dpc) {
                    [editedinsArray addObject:tempinssDictionary];

                }
            }

            // by now you should have three things
            // 1, access to your ins coredata object //this s wrong I actually have access to insProject
            // 2, the values you need to be edited saved into a NSArray (editedinsArray, which will be used to check against and keep old values correct)
            // 3, UpdatedNSD which will be used to update any values that need to be updated.


            // go through your values and update the ins object
            int i = 0;
            for (ins *temp in editedinsArray) {
                NSDictionary *currentEditedins = [editedinsArray objectAtIndex:i];
                i++;

                // these values should stay the same so use currentEditedins which contains old vals
                NSString *stringToNumberDpc = [currentEditedins valueForKey:@"dpc"];
                int tempDpcNum = [stringToNumberDpc integerValue];
                NSNumber *dpcNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:tempDpcNum];
                temp.dpc = dpcNumber;

                NSString *totDQtyString = [currentEditedins valueForKey:@"totDQty"];
                if ((NSNull *)totDQtyString == [NSNull null]) {
                    temp.totDQty = @"";
                } else {
                    temp.totDQty = totDQtyString;
                }

                NSString *totShipString = [currentEditedins valueForKey:@"totShip"];
                if ((NSNull *)totShipString == [NSNull null]) {
                    temp.totShip = @"";
                } else {
                    temp.totShip = totShipString;
                }


                // values to be updated so use updatedNSD wthich was passed in as method param with the new vals
                temp.newInsComp = [updatedNSD valueForKey:@"newInsComp"];
                temp.newDryComp = [updatedNSD valueForKey:@"newDryComp"];
                temp.updatedRow = [updatedNSD valueForKey:@"updatedRow"];

            }
#warning --- I have no idea what to do here... i.e. how do I update the tempInsProjectArray.ins values I have just updated in the above for loop then save context which I hope would update insProj and the ins entities involved.         

            //save
            [context save:&error];


        }

}
```

As you can see at the bottom of the code with #warning I explain where I am having the issue. if I log temp inside the for loop I see the updated values perfectly the issue I am having is how do I then update the current tempInsProjectArray.ins values that I have just edited? then save them of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is in great need of simplification. Some ground rules:

1. Use names with smallInitial and camelCase for variables. So not `InsProjectDictionaryArray` but `insProjectDictionaryArray`.
2. The same applies to dictionary keys indicating attribute names of managed objects. So `projNo`, not `ProjNo`.
3. Avoid cryptic abbreviations. Use plain and readable English Not `projNo` but `projectNumber`. What is an `Ins`? What is "dcp"?
4. Don't use the plural form for entity names. An suitable name for an item is `Item`, not `Items`
5. Don't use the mutable versions of dictionary and array when immutable ones would do.
6. Avoid duplicating your data, such as in `[array copy]`.
7. Avoid dictionaries when you have an object graph. The object graph is what core data creates. It renders dictionaries with values and keys unnecessary.
8. Don't use IDs. The object graph renders those unnecessary as well in most cases. If you use IDs, do not use strings but numbers, such as long ints, or the object version `NSNumber`.
9. When fetching data from the Core Data persistent store, don't fetch all the data and the filter the result. Fetch only the data you need.

What you want to accomplish can surely be done in a few lines of code. I will try to summarize what you want to do as far as I understand it.

Your data model looks something like this:

```
Project <----->> Item
```

Where the items are in a to-many relationship called `ins`. I will rename this `items`. I will also assume that you will refactor your IDs to be of type `NSNumber`.

All the code up to `myArray` could be substituted with this:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:"Project"];
request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"projectID = %@", projectID];
request.fetchLimit = 1;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [self.managedObjectContext 
      executeFetchRequest:request error:nil]; 
Project *project = fetchedObjects[0];
```

You now have all items available simply with `project.items`. I understand that there could be more than one item with a mysterious attribute `dcp` of type `int` (i.e. `NSNumber` for managed objects), that is equal to the `dcp` parameter passed.

```
NSSet *matchingItems = [project.items filteredSetUsingPredicate:
    [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dcp = %@", @(dcp)]];
```

Now it becomes a bit murky. Why do you have type `ins` in your for loop if the `ins` are actually of type `Item`? You then cast them into a dictionary... This should generate a compiler error. Or you have another class called `ins` instead of `Ins`??

Anyway, if you stay with the Items you can just update the values with what you pass in your dictionary:

```
for (Item *item in matchingItems) {
  item.newInsComp = [updatedNSD valueForKey:@"newInsComp"];
  item.newDryComp = [updatedNSD valueForKey:@"newDryComp"];
  item.updatedRow = [updatedNSD valueForKey:@"updatedRow"];
}

[self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
```

Done!

BTW you could make it even shorter by setting the entity name of the fetch request to "Item" and setting the following predicate:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"project.projectID = %@ && dcp = %@", 
     projectID, @(dcp)];
```

Comment: Mundi, thank you very much for taking the time to reply to me. I have printed out your suggestions and am going to make sure I do a better job from now on regarding the rules you outlined. I think possibly the problem exassibated the quality of my code as I have sort of been caught up trying to achive something I was unware of how to achive. (if that makes sense) anyway. I am going to give your answer a go as well. I will post back with my results.. again thank you very much for answering and taking the time to read my question.

Comment: Im currently working through it but I am getting an error when the thread hits the line where you declare NSArray fetched objects. this is the error I get "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath projectID not found in entity <NSSQLEntity InsProject id=2>'"

Comment: Check your attribute names both in the managed object subclasses and in the object model. This error is quite explicit, you could have figured it out.

Comment: Sorry feel like a complete idiot.. I could have sworn black and blue that projectID was correct, but it was actually projID.. I am really sorry about that. okay just working through the next part..

Comment: So I logged Project.ins to see what I would get back and it says I have a "<relationship fault: 0x1d5139d0 'ins'>"; so im going to have to figure out whats causing this.... which I think is causing the issue with the nsset line of code. (UPDATE: i just read this "A fault in Core Data is not an error, it just means that the what you are trying to access hasn't been retrieved from the database yet. ") how do you think I would solve this then?

Comment: okay fixed the fault by adding this under NSFetchRequest decliration. [request setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"ins",nil]]; works like a gem. However I still get an access error when I hit the NSSet. I have checked and there is a value in it that contains that same dpc. and I have also updated your code where you have said dcp which is incorrect but still reciving the error.

Comment: okay its definatly  NSSet *matchingItems = [installProject.install filteredSetUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"dpc = %@", dpc]]; for some reason its creating the access error. I have tried to create my own variant of this using a predicate.. but have failed each time because I cant figure out how to access the ins part of insProject.

Answer (score 1):

If you know your `InProject`, then updating your `Ins` related to that project is a matter of editing property values on your managed objects.

Why not use the predicate to get an NSManagedObject of the `InProject`, then pull the relationship off of that and edit the values?

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

if (!context) {
    return;
}

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"InsProject" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the predicate on the Core Data fetch request instead
    fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ProjID==%@",projIDString];

NSError *error;
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

// We now have an array that has objects matching the projectIdString
// Might want to do some additional checks if you're only expecting zero or one objects
InsProject *aProject = [fetchedObjects lastObject];

// If we have no project, no point going any further
if ( !aProject ) return;

// On this NSManagedObject is an NSSet property with all related Ins objects
for ( Ins *anIns in aProject.ins ) {

    // If our Ins item matches the passed dpc...
    if ( [ins.dpc integerValue] == dpc ) {

        // ...we have a match, edit properties
        ins.dpc = @(dpc);
        ins.newInsComp = [updatedNSD valueForKey:@"newInsComp"];
        ins.newDryComp = [updatedNSD valueForKey:@"newDryComp"];
        ins.updatedRow = [updatedNSD valueForKey:@"updatedRow"];
    }
}

// These are managed objects, so saving the context saves all the changes
NSError *saveError;
[context save:&saveError];
if ( saveError ) {
    NSLog(@"Save error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: okay. I am going to go over this with a fine tooth combe and hopefully ill not only get it but it will work.. will keep you updated. and thank you very much for taking the time to read my question and provide an answer

Comment: I have put your code into my project just to see if there would be any warnings and I recived one "Local declaration of 'project' hides instance variable" which happens on the line where you check  if we have a project and return if we dont.

Comment: @HurkNburkS Rename the "project" variable to something else and that should fix that. You obviously have another property/iVar elsewhere in your class called `project`